# Rewrite Rule - Remove numbers after forward slash

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a bunch of 404 links, close to 500 resulting from a link looking like:

http://www.domain.com/component/k2/item/192-file-sharing-options-to-consider.html

The link needs to be shown as follows, except the ID 192 and portion after is an ALIAS for a blog item.

http://www.domain.com/component/k2/item/file-sharing-options-to-consider.html

We essentially need to remove the '192-' from the link, and have this happen to all blog links (the number can be anything from 1, 2, or 3 digits)

I've tried something of this sorts

```
    RewriteCond /component/k2/item/
    RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)$ /component/k2/item/$1
```

I know this may not be proper, but I am slowly trying to learn how this all works.

Also /component/k2/item/ can be found as /blog/item/ in some links

Updated for htaccess:

```
    ##
    # @version $Id: htaccess.txt 21064 2011-04-03 22:12:19Z dextercowley $
    # @package Joomla
    # @copyright Copyright (C) 2005 - 2010 Open Source Matters. All rights reserved.
    # @license http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/gpl.html GNU/GPL
    # Joomla! is Free Software
    ##


    #####################################################
    #  READ THIS COMPLETELY IF YOU CHOOSE TO USE THIS FILE
    #
    # The line just below this section: 'Options +FollowSymLinks' may cause problems
    # with some server configurations.  It is required for use of mod_rewrite, but may already
    # be set by your server administrator in a way that dissallows changing it in
    # your .htaccess file.  If using it causes your server to error out, comment it out (add # to
    # beginning of line), reload your site in your browser and test your sef url's.  If they work,
    # it has been set by your server administrator and you do not need it set here.
    #
    #####################################################

    ##  Can be commented out if causes errors, see notes above.
    Options +FollowSymLinks

    #
    #  mod_rewrite in use

    RewriteEngine On

    ########## Begin - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits
    ## If you experience problems on your site block out the operations listed below
    ## This attempts to block the most common type of exploit `attempts` to Joomla!
    #
    ## Deny access to extension xml files (uncomment out to activate)
    #<Files ~ "\.xml$">
    #Order allow,deny
    #Deny from all
    #Satisfy all
    #</Files>
    ## End of deny access to extension xml files
    # Block out any script trying to set a mosConfig value through the URL
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} mosConfig_[a-zA-Z_]{1,21}(=|\%3D) [OR]
    # Block out any script trying to base64_encode data within the URL
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\) [OR]
    # Block out any script that includes a <script> tag in URL
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
    # Block out any script trying to set a PHP GLOBALS variable via URL
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
    # Block out any script trying to modify a _REQUEST variable via URL
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
    # Return 403 Forbidden header and show the content of the root homepage
    RewriteRule .* index.php [F]
    #
    ########## End - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits


    ########## Begin - Custom redirects
    #
    # If you need to redirect some pages, or set a canonical non-www to
    # www redirect (or vice versa), place that code here. Ensure those
    # redirects use the correct RewriteRule syntax and the [R=301,L] flags.
    #
    #K2 to new blog plugin redirect

    #Strips blog ID- from URL and rewrites to blog/item
    RewriteRule ^(component/k2/item)/[0-9]+-(.+)$ /$1/$2 [L,NC]
    Redirect /component/k2/item/ http://www.managemyitinc.com/blog/item/

    redirect 301  /blog/entry/ http://www.managemyitinc.com/blog/item/
    redirect 301  /blog/categories/listings/ http://www.managemyitinc.com       /blog/categories/categories/listings/

    #Non www to www
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^managemyitinc.com$
    RewriteRule (.*) http://www.managemyitinc.com/$1 [R=301,L] 

    ########## End - Custom redirects


    #  Uncomment following line if your webserver's URL
    #  is not directly related to physical file paths.
    #  Update Your Joomla! Directory (just / for root)

    # RewriteBase /


    ########## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section
    #
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
    #
    # If the requested path and file is not /index.php and the request
    # has not already been internally rewritten to the index.php script
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
    # and the request is for root, or for an extensionless URL, or the
    # requested URL ends with one of the listed extensions
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/[^.]*|\.(php|html?|feed|pdf|raw))$ [NC]
    # and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical file
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    # and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical folder
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    # internally rewrite the request to the index.php script
    RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
    #
    ########## End - Joomla! core SEF Section
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this rule as your first rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(component/k2/item)/[0-9]+-(.+)$ /$1/$2 [L,R=301,NC]
```

This needs to be in `DocumentRoot/.htaccess`

Comment: This oddly works with the non-www link, not this: http://www.managemyitinc.com/component/k2/item/258-tip-how-to-set-your-homepage-on-your-web-browser.html

Comment: This rule has nothing to www or non-www. May be you have other rules also. Can you paste your .htaccess in question

Comment: Is `/component/k2/item/` a directory?

Comment: I've updated my post with htaccess contents. /component/k2/item/ is a generated URL from Joomla. This link works, just not the WWW version: - managemyitinc.com/component/k2/item/258-tip-how-to-set-your-homepage-on-your-web-browser.html

Comment: ok first make this rule as your first rule (place it just below `RewriteEngine On` line) 2nd is comment out `Redirect /component/k2/item/ http://www.managemyitinc.com/blog/item/` and a rule above this line.

Comment: I moved the rules you provided right under the RewriteEngine On, and commented these out as instructed. This does still not work.

Comment: No `Redirect` line is still uncommented. And you have `RewriteRule ^(component/k2/item)/[0-9]+-(.+)$ /$1/$2 [L,NC]` instead of `RewriteRule ^(component/k2/item)/[0-9]+-(.+)$ /$1/$2 [L,NC,R=301]`

Comment: I have `R=301` that you're missing.

Comment: That worked, I assumed remove the 301 redirect until this was tested working, to avoid restarting browser. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome, glad it worked. For testing you can just use `R=302` then you won't need to restart browser.

Comment: Just curious, why does the 301 being removed affect this?

Comment: Because with `R` URL change in internal and Joomla doesn't find the correct component with internal rewrite. So R=301 or R=302 will work